# trying to figure out a route in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

im trying to understand a laravel code. im newto laravel. what i need to know is how to find the route mentioned in form action. route pages are web.php,api.php, admin.php, console.php, fleet.php

id )}}>

Comment: `artisan routes:list`

Comment: @u_mulder It's `route:list`

Comment: What is the route you're looking for?

Comment: action="{{route('admin.user.update', $user->id )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **php artisan route:list** this will list all available routes with all of the information. :)

Comment: [LogicException]
  Key path "file://C:\xampp\........\storage\oauth-private.key" does not exist or is not readable

Comment: that is completely different issue. Where did you try the above command??

Comment: i use php strom. i used the command in its terminal. i used it in my cmd too. i was inside the project folder when i used it

Comment: The second error seems to be related to permission Check this out for detail info https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/418

Answer (score 1):

```
php artisan route:list
```

use this command 
and give permissions to your storage folder for [LogicException] Key path "file://C:\xampp........\storage\oauth-private.key" does not exist or is not readabl
this error

```
sudo chmod -R 777 storage
```

let me know if you have any issue